# How to work with an asymmetrical distribution

Tags: distributions, sigma-algebra

I'm looking at estimated and actual time taken for a range of projects, as these vary in length quite a lot I've normalised them so they are just estimate/actual, so an estimate of 16 days work that took 12 days shows as 0.75 and estimate of 5 days work that took 7 shows as 1.40.

The total estimate/actual for all the projects is 1.09 so on average the estimates are ok and many are within 10% (45/127), but individually there is a very wide range. I can see the data is asymmetrical, of course nothing can be completed in less than zero time, but more generally there are about as many projects in the 1.0 -> 2.0 range as there are in the 0.5 -> 1.0 range. I believe  this may follow for any 1.0 -> x vs 1/x -> 1.0.

0.23    0.36    0.48    0.50    0.50    0.50    0.58    0.58    0.60    0.63    0.63    0.65    0.69    0.69    0.70    0.71    0.72    0.73    0.75    0.75    0.75    0.80    0.81    0.83    0.83    0.83    0.83    0.83    0.86    0.86    0.88    0.88    0.88    0.89    0.90    0.91    0.91    0.91    0.92    0.94    0.95    0.95    0.96    0.96    0.97    0.97    0.97    0.98    0.98    0.99    0.99    0.99    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.02    1.02    1.03    1.04    1.05    1.06    1.06    1.08    1.09    1.09    1.10    1.11    1.11    1.14    1.14    1.15    1.15    1.17    1.17    1.19    1.20    1.20    1.20    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.22    1.24    1.24    1.25    1.26    1.28    1.28    1.29    1.32    1.33    1.34    1.36    1.39    1.40    1.41    1.42    1.46    1.58    1.60    1.61    1.63    1.75    1.81    1.82    1.94    2.12    2.15    2.44    2.56    2.67    2.73

If this were a standard distribution I would work out the sigma value and put a value on the accuracy of the estimates. I could then compare the sigma values between years to see if estimating accuracy is improving.

Is there an equivalent or a transformation I can use to apply the same to this asymmetrical distribution?

Comment: There are many possibilities including a Box-Cox transformation.  Sometimes a log or square root transformation can work.

Comment: The "sigma-algebra" tag appears irrelevant here (the tag does not refer to the "standard deviation"("sigma") that appears to be what the OP is interested in).

Answer (score 1):

Your data exhibits some strange behavior. One choice is to fit a skewed distribution to the data. First, we can examine the Cullen-Frey plot.[image]

Since the blue dot appears to be on the dashed line, we might try fitting a Gamma distribution to the data. Using the $\texttt{fitdist}$ function in R, we find MLE for the shape and rate parameters to be: $\alpha = 7.8$ and $\beta=7.1$. Here is a histogram of your data, where the red curve is the fitted Gamma distribution.
[image]
Your data seems to have a peak at 1, which is going to be hard to capture with a parametric distribution.

---

Since your primary interest is looking at the estimation over time, you might try the following. Create data by doing $x_i = est_i - act_i$. Your sample size is large enough so that the 1 sample t-procedures should apply. Search for Matched Pairs t-procedures on the web for details. You could construct a confidence interval for the difference by doing:

$$\bar X \pm t^*\frac{S_X}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Where $\bar{X}$ and $S_X$ are the sample mean and standard deviation of the data and where $t^*$ is your critical value which controls the confidence and should come from a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. For your problem, (with $n=127$) a 95% confidence interval would require $t^* = 1.979$.

Do this for various years and see how it changes. This may be a good start.

Comment: There's a clear issue with a lognormal model -- see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcBjx.png) more detailed histogram of the logs for example. It might or might not be a particular problem depending on what the model is being used for.